# How prevent multiple script file loading

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website, where I can select an Excel file. After selecting I print the filedata in a html table under the fileselect (for checking and editing). Below the table are some buttons and one of them is to upload the table data to a database. For that I'm going through the button click to a JS function, where I store the table data in a multidimensional array. To upload the data I post the array to my php-file. After successful upload I want to show a modal. And thats what my problem is: the modal doesn't appear.
Here is my shorten code:

**home.php** (html of the website with fileselect)

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="web.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary">
                            Datei auswählen&hellip; <input type="file" name="file" style="display: none;">
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>              
                </br>
                <button id="excelBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Excel-Datei anzeigen</button>                                                        
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_FILES['file'])){     //executed after fileselect 
                include "upload.php";      //show file as table on website, works fine
            }

            if(isset($_POST['data'])){     //is executed when returning from JS
                //upload all array data
                //after successful upload do:
                include "modal_success.php";  //this php works, will not show extra
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: modal_success.php

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Speichern</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Die Daten des Mitarbeiters wurden erfolgreich in die Datenbank geschrieben.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="geheZuHome()">Zurück zur Startseite</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Weitere Datei hochladen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script> 
    $("#modal").modal("show");
</script>
```

**upload.php**

```html
<!-- print data as table -->
<form  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button id="exBtnEnable" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block" disabled=false onclick="editTable(<?php echo $taID ?>)">Bearbeiten aktivieren</button>
    <button id="exBtnHoch" name="exBtnHoch" onclick="saveInArray()" type="button"  class="btn btn-success btn-block">Excel-Datei hochladen</button>
    <button id="exBtnAbbr" type="button" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Abbrechen</button>
</form>
```

My **web.js**:

```js
function saveInArray(){
    //save data in array
    var arrString = JSON.stringify(tableData);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('post', 'home.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('data=' + arrString);
}
```

First I had a save.php where I did the upload to database, but for the modal it was the wrong location. So I took all the code to home.php. Now the location is right but it won't show again. 
I thought there could be a problem with multiple file bindings in home.php(bootstrap javascript). Can you confirm it? Or how can I solve it?

It's a project which I took over, so most structure was already there.

Comment: Did you miss to add the part with the modal and where you trigger the modal?

Comment: It's in modal_success.php(included in home.php). There I have following js code after html code: $("#modal").modal("show");

Comment: If your problem is the modal it would be good if you add the content of that file too. :-)

Comment: Did it, but I don't think that there is a problem. When I include it in home.php in first if-statement, the modal appears.

Comment: Have you tried to include already faded in modal instead of opening it from jquery

Comment: No, but can’t try it, I’m in holidays now. What should I change. Didn’t found a good example of such modal

Answer (score 0):

In your `home.php` change

```
$_POST['data']
```

to

```
$_POST['daten']
```

or in your `web.js` change

```
request.send('daten=' + arrString);
```

to

```
request.send('data=' + arrString);
```

and the modal should work.

**EDIT:**

I see the problem(*s*) now.

1. Where do you load your `web.js`?
2. Even if `saveInArray` is called, you don't do anything whit the response.

Possible (*but dirty*) solution:

Change your `web.js`

```
function saveInArray() {
    // save data in array
    var arrString = JSON.stringify(tableData);

    $.post('home.php', {data: arrString}).done(function(response)
    {
        $('body').html($(response).find('body').html());
    });
}
```

This does a AJAX call with [jQuery's post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function and replaces the whole body.

Comment: My fault , I changed the names for better understanding. In second if-statement it does the php part , but the modal isn't shown.

Comment: @Eddy_SPL In your `upload.php` change `//print data as table` to `<!-- print data as table -->`. But i dont see why the modal does not work inside the first if statement but not inside the second. :-|

Comment: I thought that maybe it loads the bootstrap javascript in home.php a second time when the request is send ?! :-|

Comment: @Eddy_SPL The problem is the AJAX request. Check my edit in the answer.

Comment: web.js is loaded, where bootstrap js is loaded in home.php. I tried your code, but nothing happend :(

Comment: @Eddy_SPL Looks like jQuery slim misses this features. If you can, switch to full jQuery.

Comment: Don't know if you meant that, but I downloaded a jquery file version 3.4.1, and it doesn't changed anything

Comment: Then you should check the console maybe.

Comment: There was one error , caused by the bootstrap.min.js. After replacing it with a normal bootstrap.js the error was gone but nothing appears :-|